# How should I add a new user into a list of users with in a "group" model in mongoose using node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a project that manages groups of a specific user in Node. Each group has a list of members, the creator of the group has the privilege of adding members to the list of members in that group. Where should I set up the member and add it to the list in the group?

I have tried to first create the member from the user request and call the group and it's members list then add the newly created member.

```
    // const group = this.getGroupDetail; 
    const member = new Member({
      username: req.body.name,
      bio:req.body.bio,
      groups:[],
      paid:false,
      comments:[],
      joinedAt: Date.now()
    });

    group.members.push()
      .then(member => {
        res.status(201).json({
          message: "member added successfully",
          group: {
            ...member,
            id: member._id
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json({
          message: "Adding a member failed"
        });
    });
};
```

I expect the result to be the group's members list should have the newly added member.

`Group {
    id:12352,
    members:[memberId1,memberID2,...]
}`